# Analysis Grid on Logi Info Studio refresh issues on IE 10

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting

I' using Analysis Grid from Logi Info Studio to display an report which have visible by default columns and invisible columns, when i try to change columns status from visible to invisible and contrary, the report still keep the original columns. 
I added 'rdAgRefreshData' as a default parameter and set it to 'True' but the problem persist. 
This problem is reproduced only on IE 10, other versions or browsers work fine.
Cann anyone help with a solution?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If IE is using compatibility view there can be issues with the analysis grid. Try turning off compatibility view in IE. Compatibility View settings are located in the "tools>compatibility view settings" menu.

I hope this helps!